# MS Charts version 3.5 in VS2012 giving an error in the designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5, mschart

We have just upgraded to VS2012 from VS2010.  However, any form with a chart control on it will not load in the designer (although it compiles and runs OK).  We are using the .Net 3.5 version of MSCharts and cannot go to .Net 4.0.

We are getting errors like:

> Could not find type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

The chart control works fine in VS2010, and I have double checked that we have the correct dll referenced, so this looks a lot like a bug in VS2012.

Does anyone know if there is a patch/service pack for this bug?

If not, has anybody figured out a workaround?